# Why some sites are using http:\/\/ instead of http:// in JSON?

Tags: json, backslash

Why `http:\/\/` instead of `http://`?

```html
<script type="application/ld+json">
        {
"@context": "http:\/\/schema.org",
"@type": "NewsArticle",
"mainEntityOfPage": {
    "@type": "WebPage",
    "@id": "http:\/\/example.com\/"
}
</script>
```

Is there a particular reason behind this usage?

Answer (score 1):

There is no good reason to escape a slash in a JSON (or JavaScript) string, no. It has no effect whatsoever; with or without the backslash, it's the same string. E.g.: `"//" === "\/\/"` is true.

Sometimes things like this are output in PHP via `json_encode`, which entirely-unnecessarily adds backslashes in front of slashes in strings by default (there's a flag to disable the pointless behavior, but it's not the default). So you might be seeing something output that way.